# Create files from extracted content of one file

Tags: python, bash, matplotlib, awk

I have a large file which contains information based on the number of `processes` and `benchmark` case used. All this information is followed one after the other within the same file.

```
    --
# Benchmarking Allgather
# #processes = 8
# ( 3592 additional processes waiting in MPI_Barrier)
#----------------------------------------------------------------
       #bytes #repetitions  t_min[usec]  t_max[usec]  t_avg[usec]
            0         1000         0.05         0.05         0.05
            1         1000         1.77         2.07         1.97
            2         1000         1.79         2.08         1.97
            4         1000         1.79         2.07         1.98
            8         1000         1.82         2.12         2.01
--
# Benchmarking Allgather
# #processes = 16
# ( 3584 additional processes waiting in MPI_Barrier)
#----------------------------------------------------------------
       #bytes #repetitions  t_min[usec]  t_max[usec]  t_avg[usec]
            0         1000         0.05         0.05         0.05
            1         1000         2.34         2.85         2.73
            2         1000         2.36         2.87         2.74
            4         1000         2.38         2.90         2.76
            8         1000         2.42         2.95         2.79
```

In order to quickly plot the information I was planning to create a file per independent content, for instance, with the information given above I would create two files called "Allgather_8" and "Allgather_16" and the expected content of these files would be:

```
$cat Allgather_8
  #bytes #repetitions  t_min[usec]  t_max[usec]  t_avg[usec]
            0         1000         0.05         0.05         0.05
            1         1000         1.77         2.07         1.97
            2         1000         1.79         2.08         1.97
            4         1000         1.79         2.07         1.98
            8         1000         1.82         2.12         2.01
$cat Allgather_16
 #bytes #repetitions  t_min[usec]  t_max[usec]  t_avg[usec]
            0         1000         0.05         0.05         0.05
            1         1000         2.34         2.85         2.73
            2         1000         2.36         2.87         2.74
            4         1000         2.38         2.90         2.76
            8         1000         2.42         2.95         2.79
```

I could then plot this with *gnuplot* or *matplotlib*.

**What I have tried so far:**

I have been using grep and awk to extract the content, which works for independent sections but I don't know how to automate this.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the de-limiter separating them `--`? as above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk '
/Benchmarking/ { close(out); out = $NF }
/#processes/   { out = out "_" $NF }
/^[[:space:]]/ { print > out }
' file
```

Comment: @_Ed Morton: Spot on!